# Do limits pass through measurable functions just as it passes continuous ones? Royden 4.4 (35)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $f$ be a real-valued function of two variables $(x,y)$ that is defined on the square $Q=\{(x,y):0<x<1,0<y<1\}$ and is a measurable function of x for each fixed value of $y$.Suppose for each fixed value of $x$ ,$\lim_{y\to 0}(x,y)=f(x)$ and that for all $y$, we have $|f(x,y)|<g(x)$, where $g$ is integrable over $[0,1]$. Show that $$\lim_{y\to 0}\int_0^1f(x,y) dx = \int_0^1f(x) dx.$$ Also show that if the function $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $y$ for each $x$, then $$ h(y)=\int_0^1 f(x,y) dx$$ is a continuous function of $y$.

So this entire question is setup for Dominated Convergence Theorem. Hence I naturally thought to make $\lim_{y \to 0} f(x,y) = f(x)$ into $\lim_{y_n \to 0} f(x,y_n) = f(x)$ and set $F(y_n) = f(x,y_n)$ but I wasn't sure if this was allowed.

Now after googling, I found [solutions](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~hchang/19s321_HW6_sol.pdf)
 which sets $F(x) = f(x,1/n)$, but I view this more or less what I was trying to do, so can limits pass through measurables too?

Comment: (0) I can't view pictures(please type the question?), so maybe I'm way off the mark, but (1) depending on what you mean by a measurable function, you can't even evaluate the function at a point (2) there exist discontinuous measurable functions, so no, you will have to assume continuity or some other assumption, maybe first assume that the function is continuous and then use an approximation argument etc

Comment: It's not true for measurable functions in general.  "Limits pass through" is essentially the *definition* of continuity and can fail for functions that are not continuous, even if they are measurable.  However, pay attention to the second sentence of the problem - $f$ is not just any old measurable function.

Comment: @CalvinKhor u have to click on the picture.

Comment: @Hawk No, bad internet

Comment: `Let $f$ be a real-valued function of two variables $(x,y)$ that is defined on the square $Q=\{(x,y):0<x<1,0<y<1\}$ and is a measurable function of x for each fixed value of $y$.Suppose for each fixed value of $x$ ,$\lim_{y\to 0}(x,y)=f(x)$ and that for all $y$, we have
$|f(x,y)|<g(x)$, where $g$ is integrable over $[0,1]$. Show that
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\int_0^1f(x,y) dx = \int_0^1f(x) dx.$$
Also show that if the function $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $y$ for each $x$, then
$$ h(y)=\int_0^1 f(x,y) dx$$
is a continuous function of $y$.` From my copy of Royden. Please type questions in the future

Comment: @NateEldredge you mean that the limit is true for all $y$?

Comment: Right.  The idea is to arbitrarily choose a sequence $y_n$ that converges to $0$, and consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = f(x, y_n)$.  (Maybe this is what you had in mind, but what you wrote looks garbled.)  Because of the assumption, you have $f_n \to f$ pointwise.  Now using dominated convergence, you conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x, y_n)\,dx = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$.  Finally, since the sequence $y_n$ was arbitrary, you get the desired statement for the functional limit.

Comment: This seems like silly exercise... anyways thanks.